# Access the data set in the parent component using setState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a *parent component A*  which is setting the state of an object

```
setDetails(obj) {
  this.setState({
      types: obj,
      currentStep: 2 //Next step Details
    });
  }

render() {
 <ListComponent
     types={this.setDetails.bind(this)}
 />
}
```

*List Component*

```
render() {    
    <DetailsComponent
       types={this.props.types}
     />
    }
```

*Details Component* 
I am setting the value of types which will invoke the parent component and set the value of types. Now I want to access the types in my List Component. 
IS there any way to do that?

Comment: Which one is the Parent component of `ListComponent` ?

Comment: parent component A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent Component A

```
setDetails(obj) {
  this.setState({
      types: obj,
      currentStep: 2 //Next step Details
    });
  }

render() {
 <ListComponent
     callback={this.setDetails.bind(this)}
     types={this.state.types}
 />
}
```

List Component

```
render() {    
    <DetailsComponent
       callback={this.props.callback}
       types={this.props.types}
     />
 }
```

in your Details Component use the `this.props.callback` to set the values of types. once the types are updated the render will be called and you will get updated data of types in the List Component as `this.props.types`

Answer (score 1):

You can seperatly pass `state` and `method to set state` to `ListComponent` from `A`(parent) like below:

```
Parent A
setDetails = (obj) => {
  this.setState({
      types: obj,
      currentStep: 2 //Next step Details
    });
  }

render() {
 <ListComponent
     setType={this.setDetails}
     types={this.state.types}
 />
}

List Component
render() {    
    <DetailsComponent
       setType={this.props.setType}
       types={this.props.types}
     />
    }
```

Now, Inside child(`ListComponent`), you can call `this.props.setType()` to set state in parent component. Once state is set in parent, you will get those values in child via `this.props.types`.